# flex monkey status showing not connected

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have  flex application ie flight reservation . I'm able to run it in flash builder but how test it in flex monkey .kindly help me out.I'm using flash builder 4 with sdk 4 in compatible mode with flex 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called 'tests' within you main project folder. In flexMonkey: File>New Project, point the Project Directory to the 'tests' folder you created. A 'Project Configuration' box will appear.

Make sure to click on the + beside Setup Guide, and copy over the SWC and include the Compiler settings as advised.

The connector will only turn green in Flex Monkey once the project is run from Flex Builder

Have you gone through these steps already???